# Confguration SpecFlow feature code generation to use "locally" sequential table suffixes

Tags: specflow

Whenever I add/remove a table in one feature file it seems to affect the code generation of the other features. This causes a lot of unnecessary files to be added to commits.

For example, this diff was caused by a change in a completely different feature:

[image]

Is there a way to configure the code generation to use locally sequential suffixes? i.e. I want all suffixes for a particular feature should start at `table1` or `table0` instead of continuing from the value in the "previous" feature. This way changing a table in one feature has no impact on the code generation of another.

I am using SpecFlow v3.70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpecFlow 3 generates the code-behind files using MS Build. It is recommended to remove all `*.feature.cs` files from version control for precisely the same reason you asked your question. These auto generated files exhibit a lot of churn, so version control is not beneficial. The real benefit is adding the feature files themselves to version control. The `.feature.cs` files become an artifact of the build process, rather than an asset that requires tracking.